# Need to use functionality of iLoc, but for Dictionary values (text)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to make an API call that pulls the value of a column within a spreadsheet and sends it as a param within the API call.

I've done this successfully before with this code, but that was for integer values. Now I need to do it with text and they are stored as Dict values which give me an error.

Here is what I'm trying to use:

```
for i in range(10):
    r = requests.post(
        url = "DummyAPIEndpoint", 
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'ApiKey DummyKey',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            }, 
        params = {
            {   

                'data' : mt.iloc [i,0]
            }


        }
    )

    print(r)
```

When my values are all integers, the mt.iloc [i,0] pulls every entry in the first column and fires an API call with that value under 'data'. However, since this content is text, I get the error:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

I understand why I'm getting this error, I'm just not sure what to do about it.

How can I add the text value of the column within the spreadsheet as the param "data"?

Comment: Umm... if you're making a post request here... are you sure you aren't meant to be using `json={...}` (that'll automatically set the `Content-Type` header for you...) instead of `params={...}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has `params` in an extra set of braces.

This is interpreted as a dict.

You don't want that.

You'll want to remove the extra braces like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    r = requests.post(
        url = "DummyAPIEndpoint", 
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'ApiKey DummyKey',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            }, 
        params = {
            'data' : mt.iloc [i,0]
        }
    )

    print(r)
```